# функция ± месяц, как лучше составить?

Tags: javascript

есть две кнопки, -месяц и +месяц, при клике на которые дата должна изменится, суть вопроса, как получить новую дату на месяц меньше/больше, например если к дате 31.01 прибавить месяц, получим 31 февраля, js автоматически распределит на март, а как сделать, чтобы получаемая дата в случае выхода за рамки следующего месяца, не распределялась на соседний месяц, а исправлялась на последнее число нужного месяца,
если прибавляем к 31.01 месяц, надо перейти к 28(или 29) февраля,

Comment: Нужно исходить вообще из целей. Потому что работа с датами - это совсем не тривиальная задача. И проблема с февралём - **лишь одна из многих**... И понятие "месяц" может быть разным. У кого-то он чисто 30 дней, как раз чтобы избежать всех нюансов, у кого-то - другое.... Лучше понять задачу, чем производить какие-то калькулятивные вычисления с датой.

Comment: Например если задача: нужно что-то делать каждое конкретное число каждого месяца -это одна задача и становится проще.

Comment: Ну а самое простое, что можно сделать - это брать номер месяца, куда требуется прийти, смотреть сколько у него дней, если меньше, чем указанное число, то брать максимальное от target месяца. Как бэ всё.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский по-моему очень толково сказали, запостите как ответ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, по-моему, у меня проще. А ещё тебя зовут в комментах под моим ответом - вероятно автор перепутал, где коммент писать.

Answer (score 2):

1. Добавляем месяц.
2. Если получившийся месяц отличается от исходного не на 1 (а на 2 по модулю 12), то устанавливаем число в 0 и получаем последний день нужного месяца.

```js
function addMonth(date) {
  var d = new Date(date)
  var m = d.getMonth()
  
  d.setMonth(m + 1)

  if (d.getMonth() !== (m + 1) % 12) {
    d.setDate(0)
  }
  
  return d
}

for (const d of ['2024-01-15', '2024-01-31', '2023-01-31', '2000-02-29', '2024-01-01', '2023-11-30', '2023-12-31']) {
  console.log(d, addMonth(d))
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

Comment: А это как? Как добавить месяц? Просто инкрементировать? А если 13 получится?

Comment: @rotabor, добавил код и исправил баги.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, цель, просто перейти на следующий месяц, в отрывном календаре, в блоке отображается день недели, число, месяц, год, эра, если в селекте выбираем нужный месяц, переходим к нужной дате, а при клике на кнопки, переходим на месяц назад или вперёд...

Comment: @rotabor, 13 ? ну об этом позаботится сам объект дата, и исправит значение месяца для следующего года...

Comment: @Qwertiy, или может лучше отнять от полученной даты, дни, ну типа, получили 3.03, и отнимаем 3 дня, вместо установить день в 0...

Comment: @Белка, а чем лучше?

Comment: @Белка, есть какое-то государство, которое изменило часовой пояс на 24 часа, чтобы у них новый год стал первым в мире - вот попробуй на этом протестировать - я так понимаю, там 31 декабря должно было исчезнуть. Впрочем, не факт, что хоть какой-то способ на этом месте сработает верно))) Когда ввели российские таймзоны, в браузерах все календари глючили, включая нативные браузерные...

Comment: @Qwertiy, не советуют получать последний день месяца, устанавливая день в 0, на том же хабре,...

Comment: @Qwertiy, государство? часовой пояс? есть методы get и set, а есть аналогичные методы с приставкой UTF, вопрос стоит вывести на страницу локальную дату, не текстом, а в элементах формы, и сделать навигацию по датам максимально удобной, через кнопки ± today,  и тд

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152083/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-).

Comment: @Qwertiy как правильно исправить этот код?

document.getElementById("plusmonth").addEventListener("click", function() { currentDate.setMonth(currentDate.getMonth() + 1); elementweekday.selectedIndex = currentDate.getDay(); elementmonthday.value = currentDate.getDate(); elementmonth.selectedIndex = currentDate.getMonth(); elementyear.value = currentDate.getFullYear(); updateDate();

Comment: @Белка, ну как-нибудь исправь...

Answer (score 0):

Как мне подсказали, для JS не принято изобретать велосипед, а нужно пользоваться готовыми библиотеками.

Поэтому отсылаю Вас к [Datejs](https://github.com/datejs/Datejs):

```
    /**
     * Adds the specified number of months to this instance. 
     * @param {Number}   The number of months to add. The number can be positive or negative [Required]
     * @return {Date}    this
     */
    $P.addMonths = function (value) {
    ...
```

Comment: А вас бы отослать к Luxon, потому что datejs уже легаси)

Comment: @VladimirGonchar и поэтому она неработоспособна? Или мы перешли на другой календарь? Посоветуйте ТС что-нибудь на свой вкус из свеженького.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar а на счёт Datejs я думаю, что автор сделал репозиторий только для чтения не потому, что что-то там устарело, а из-за большого количества веток, тратить время на которые смысла просто нет.

Comment: [Luxon](https://github.com/moment/luxon) из актуального. Репозиторий помещают в архив, потому что над ним перестают работать. Если пакет в архиве -- это огромный красный флаг, потому что: 1) пакет больше не будет обновлять свои зависимости и фиксить уязвимости, 2) в случае нахождения багов исправлять их больше некому, только если плодить форк и править руками.

Comment: И да, 1 ветка -- это не огромное количество. Форки не в счёт, их делают все кому не лень, включая и для создания PR к текущему проекту.